# Add tick labels on right yaxis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following graph:
[image: Matplotlib graph]

I'd like to add custom ticks with labels on the right hand side of the graph, to identify the dashed horizontal lines. How can I do that?

Comment: probably easiest to just add `text` objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ax = gca()
ax.axhline(.5, linestyle='--')
trans = matplotlib.transforms.blended_transform_factory(
    ax.transAxes,
    ax.transData)

ax.annotate('label', xy=(1.01, .5), xycoords=trans, clip_on=False, va='center')
ax.set_xlim([0,2])
plt.draw()
```

See [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations) for details on blended transforms.  The x coordinate in is axis units (so it will always be just a tad off to the right, and the y-coordinate is is data units so you can put it exactly where you want.  There isn't much point in putting in ticks on the right because you dashed lines will cover them up.

Comment: Wonderful! I wasn't aware of blended transforms. Your solution is very simple, and does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @CharlesBrunet I have only recently discovered them, they are quite nifty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new scale, use [`twinx()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx).

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = []
ax.append(fig.add_subplot(111))
ax.append(ax[0].twinx())
ax[0].plot(...)
ax[1].set_yticks([...])
ax[1].set_yticklabels([...])
plt.show()
```

If you want just a label, use a `text` thingy, as @tcaswell wrote.

Comment: the danger with this is that your two y-axis can have entirely different scales so you will need to be careful when re-scaling/make sure you have turned off all auto-scaling, ect.

Comment: I was deceived by the title of the question. It is more about adding a label/annotation than adding tick labels.